# Stereo Camera rectification using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, depth, stereoscopy

I have two images from my stereo camera model is ZED 1 from stereoLabs.  I want to rectify those images, This is the code I used to try that :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the calibration parameters
left_camera_matrix = np.loadtxt('left_camera_matrix.txt')
left_distortion_coefficients = np.loadtxt('left_distortion_coefficients.txt')
right_camera_matrix = np.loadtxt('right_camera_matrix.txt')
right_distortion_coefficients = np.loadtxt('right_distortion_coefficients.txt')
rotation_matrix = np.loadtxt('rotation_matrix.txt')
translation_vector = np.loadtxt('translation_matrix.txt')

# Set up the rectification parameters
image_size = (1280,720) # replace with the size of your images
R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,roi1,roi2 = cv2.stereoRectify(left_camera_matrix, left_distortion_coefficients,
                                         right_camera_matrix, right_distortion_coefficients,
                                         image_size, rotation_matrix, translation_vector,1,(0,0))
# the output of stereoRectify is a tuple of 3 elements (R1, R2, P1, P2, Q)
#R1, R2, P1, P2, Q = rectify_parameters[:5]
left_map1, left_map2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(left_camera_matrix, left_distortion_coefficients, R1, P1, image_size, cv2.CV_16SC2)
right_map1, right_map2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(right_camera_matrix, right_distortion_coefficients, R2, P2, image_size, cv2.CV_16SC2)

# Load the stereo images
left_image = cv2.imread('right2.png')
right_image = cv2.imread('left2.png')

# Rectify the stereo images
left_rectified = cv2.remap(left_image, left_map1, left_map2, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
right_rectified = cv2.remap(right_image, right_map1, right_map2, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

# Display the rectified images (optional)
cv2.imshow('Left Rectified', left_rectified)
cv2.imshow('Right Rectified', right_rectified)
cv2.imwrite('left_rectified.png', left_rectified)
cv2.imwrite('right_rectified.png', right_rectified)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I thought i would get two proper images but i get two very wrong outputs , with one image being projected towards the right side and the other one is almost completely black, These are my input images and the outputs:[left image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZwWy.jpg)[right image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVgEj.jpg)[Left rectified image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjP6U.png) [right rectified image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnx6t.png),

```
These are my intrinsic and extrinsic parameters for the stereo camera:
right_camera_matrix:  1399.700000 0.000000 991.780000
                      0.000000 1399.700000 524.748000
                      0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

Left_camera_matrix: 1400.340000 0.000000 976.990000
                    0.000000 1400.340000 534.371000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
   format for the above matrix :        [[fx, 0, cx],
                                     [0, fy, cy],
                                     [0, 0, 1]])

right_distortion: -0.172000
                   0.025300
                   0.000000
                   0.000000
                   0.000000

left_distortion: -0.170500
                  0.023500
                  0.000000
                  0.000000
                  0.000000

    format for the distortion array :  = D = np.array([k1, k2, p1, p2, k3])

extrinsic parameters :


    # Define the rotation and translation matrices
    Tx = 120.000
    Ty = 0.0000
    Tz = 0.0000
    Rx = 0.0028
     Ry = 0.0145
Rz = 0.0005

# Compute the rotation matrix from Euler angles
theta = np.sqrt(Rx**2 + Ry**2 + Rz**2)
rvec = np.array([Rx, Ry, Rz]) / theta
R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)

# Define the translation matrix
T = np.array([[Tx],
              [Ty],
              [Tz]])

# Save the rotation matrix to file
np.savetxt('rotation_matrix.txt', R, fmt='%.6f')

# Save the translation matrix to file
np.savetxt('translation_matrix.txt', T, fmt='%.6f')
```

I tried changing the parameters and the output changes however, i dont know why i am not getting proper images even though i got the parameters from Stereo Labs builtin image viewer but still output is wrong, so any idea what i am doing wrong